# Rails Delayed_Jobs trying to ssh into a server error: Premission Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, delayed-job

I have a method in my model that uses delayed_jobs and it is supposed to ssh into a server and delete files but I keep getting `Permission denied, please try again.` in my log when I see delayed_job trying to complete the task.

The following below works without putting it in delayed_jobs. It seems as if delayed_jobs is like its own user and I need to add it to my server to be able to ssh into it. I did `adduser delayed_job` that did not work, I tried `adduser DJ` that as well did not work. Keep getting the same errors as above. What would be a solution to this issue I am facing?

for testing purposes I am trying the following below

```
before_destroy :schedule_destroy

def schedule_destroy
  User.delay(run_at: 1.minutes.from_now).destroy_numbers
end

def self.destroy_numbers
 SysExecLogger.exec "ssh myserver 'rm -r /var/gluster/recordings/boop/'"
end
```

EDIT
after running  `ps -ef|grep delayed`

```
root     13324     1  0 Nov06 ?        01:36:03 /bin/sh /var/asterisk/delayed_job/safe_delayed_job
root     13490     1  0 Nov06 ?        01:20:57 delayed_job.0                                                                                                                                    
root     13498     1  0 Nov06 ?        00:37:39 delayed_job.1                                                                                                                                    
root     26447 26234  0 10:19 pts/4    00:00:00 grep delayed
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to sort out your authorised keys, as per https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/ which should allow you to SSH without a password.

The way to do this depends on what OS and Daemon is running at both ends, but hopefully that document will help

Comment: thank you for replying, but I don't see how I can make authorized keys for a gem ```delayed_jobs```. I am able to ssh into the sever without putting it in delayed_jobs.

Comment: When you ssh, you enter a password? The authorized keys bit will allow you to connect without a password, as you create a trust between the 2 computers. This isn't really a delayed job problem, it's an ssh problem

Comment: No, I don't enter a password when ssh, I am developing on server1 and server1 already has authorized keys for server2. So when I don't put my ssh code in a delayed_job it works without any issue when trying to ssh. No password is typed in when ssh

Comment: Assuming you're using Linux, `ps -ef|grep delayed` and check which user is running the delayed job command. From there you should be able to work out which root path is using, and then make sure that the id_rsa file is in the right place.

Comment: yeah, I am using linux. I entered the command in and I see this. If I am reading this correctly ```root``` is the user but root is already an added user to server2. I put the results up top in my question @jad

Comment: yuck! I hate services running as root, it's generally a security risk.  are you running all the commands as root?  are you running this system with a "fake root"?  if you're running with a fake root set, you will need to copy your id_rsa from the real root to the same position in the fake root.

Comment: yeah, it is all running as root. This is just a testing dev server. My real production server is not root for running the services. But, in this case, how should I proceed? I have root as a user already in server2

Comment: you could try forcing the identity for the connection: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/ although this still relies on access to the id_rsa file, which won't work if the system is running on a "fake root" ... have you checked the logs of the delayed_job to see if there are any more specific errors?